# C# WPF auto refresh DataGrid of parent window after making changes in ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I am on a C# WPF project. Having a `DataGrid` in my parent window which shows `firstname` and `lastname` of a person from MySQL database.

Also a button which shows dialog to insert another person name. when I insert name in the dialog it saves in the MySQL table but does not auto refresh the `DataGrid` after closing the dialog. The new name is shown in the next run of the program however it gets inserted in the table immediately.

My problem is I want to refresh the `DataGrid` of the parent `window(MainWindow)` when the child window is closed.
Seriously guys googled a lot, but didn't got the expected answer.

Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hook up an event handler to the `OnClose` event of your dialog in your parent window, and do the refreshing stuff in it..

Comment: i have added the onclose method, now how to hook it up in the parent window